# The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Admin' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I am learning Authentication/Authorization in .NET Core MVC.

I am trying to create a controller that can only be accessed by 'Admin', but get the following error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Admin' was
>   not found.

Here's my code. What should I do?

```
[HttpGet("~/Test")]
[Authorize("Admin")]
public async Task<string> MyMethod()
{
    return await Task<string>.Run(() => "Hello Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can define the matching policy in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {

        options.AddPolicy("Admin",
            authBuilder =>
            {
                authBuilder.RequireRole("Administrators");
            });

 });
```

the authBuilder has other methods on it, you can require claims or specific user names or custom rules using policy based authorization and control the rules from a central place in Startup
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html

Comment: Nice. Going to mark this as the "Correct" answer as it leads to neater code in the controllers.

Comment: is this new in Core? i didn't had such issue in classic version

Answer (score 33):

In line with the documentation [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html), you have not added the Authorization attribute correctly. This is the correct way to do it.

```
[HttpGet("~/Test")]
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
public async Task<string> MyMethod()
{
    return await Task<string>.Run(() => "Hello Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **Scheme-based authentication** then you can pass the "AuthenticationSchemes "with authorize filter.

For example, **[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "UserBasicAuth")]**

Here, your Startup.cs class should look like : AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ....>("UserBasicAuth", null)

**Instead of,** [Authorize(Policy = "UserBasicAuth")]